# Django doesn't validate or see the JWT token from Azure

Tags: python, django, azure, django-rest-framework, jwt

I used [azure-ad-verify-token 0.2.1](https://pypi.org/project/azure-ad-verify-token/) on `Django-rest` backend to validate a `jwt token` from `Microsoft Azure`, where the user is authenticated on the frontend with `React`.

According to the documentation, this library should do everything on its own.

```
from azure_ad_verify_token import verify_jwt

azure_ad_app_id = 'my app id'
azure_ad_issuer = 'https://exampletenant.b2clogin.com/0867afa-24e7-40e9-9d27-74bb598zzzzc/v2.0/'
azure_ad_jwks_uri = 'https://exampletenant.b2clogin.com/exampletenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_app_sign_in/discovery/v2.0/keys'
payload = verify_jwt(
    token='<AZURE_JWT_TO_VERIFY_HERE>',
    valid_audiences=[azure_ad_app_id],
    issuer=azure_ad_issuer,
    jwks_uri=azure_ad_jwks_uri,
    verify=True,
)

print(payload)
```

I don't understand the line `token='<AZURE_JWT_TO_VERIFY_HERE>'`, how can I put the token there?

Authorization from Azure on `React` is successful, and I get a `access jwt-token` that I can extract:

```
token = request.headers['Authorization']
```

But I need to validate it and somehow insert it into a string `token='<AZURE_JWT_TO_VERIFY_HERE>'`, but it doesn't recognize the `request` here.

How can I put a `token=` from the `header`?

And in general, is this the right way? Or am I missing something? Any help and hints would be very helpful and would be greatly appreciated. Or advise another library for `token validation` in `Python`.

Answer (score 0):

- `azure-ad-verify-token` This is used to verify the tokens received from   azure ad.
- You have to get auth tokens from azure using MSAL python library and   the azure-ad-verify-token will then verify the token.
- To retrieve the tokens, you will need MSAL python library, and it
  will also take `clientid` and `tenentd` as arguments.

`test_app=PublicClientApplication(client_id=client_id,authority="https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+tenant_id)`

`test_tokens=test_app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=scopes)`

- Now you can take the token you just received and use it in the`azure-ad-verify-token`.

`token=test_tokens['access_token']`

**Reference:**

[MSAL Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token)

[Authenticate Python apps by using the Azure SDK for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/authentication-overview)